# Using google search api cursor in angular js app to get all results for google patent search

Tags: angularjs, google-search-api

I want to make a search into google patent using the following URL which is obsolete

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/patent?v=1.0&q=thumb%20wrestling%20apparatus&userip=192.168.1.102

It gives me limited number of records per page. 
But at the end of the JSON it also returns the cursor which has start and label keys. So my question is that how can I use that cursor to show all the records in my search. Like if there are 8 pages and each page contains 4 records so I want to show all 32 records on my UI. 
How can I achieve that? 
And second question that is there REST APi for google patent search? If yes then how can I search the patent using REST API and how can I get all the records on one page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the API is restricted to a [maximum of 8 results per request](https://developers.google.com/patent-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_args) (you can increase your current 4 results to 8 by using the query param `rsz=8`.

So I guess the only way to get all results is by performing multiple requests. So if the current page info data is...

```
"pages":[
   {"start":"0","label":1},
   {"start":"8","label":2},
   {"start":"16","label":3},
   {"start":"24","label":4},
   {"start":"32","label":5}
]
```

You would make 5 requests chaining the start param `start=0, start=8 ...` and so on, extracting the results and pushing to an array store. If you're not already I recommend using something like [Restangular](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular), as it would make this process much easier.

Depending on how your UI is set out, it would be nice maybe to do this with some lazy loading as the user is scrolling through the list?

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. And how can I achieve lazy loading? That if user reaches the end of the page then it should load the next page data. How can it be done?

Comment: Lazy loading works by binding a scroll event, checking the document scroll position, if near to or at the end of the document fire off another request to get some more data. With what your are trying to do I would probably do an initial request to get the first page of data, then store the current and the last start count from the pages object. Probably also have a function that take a single parameter for the count and when the user scrolls to the bottom of the page call the function with the current start count+8. Keep doing that until the current start is greater than the last start count.